# transfer files of any size without uploading to a third-party server using php

Tags: php

I searched on Internet regarding file transfer from one place to other and found that we need to upload files and then share link with friends. Then my friend can download the file using that link.

I want to transfer files of any size without uploading to a third-party server using php for my project.

i Google on Internet regarding this n found www.pipebytes.com

what kind of mechanism it use ?
Is it possible with php language?

So that we do not have to upload any data to any server.

Thank you!!

Comment: Pipebytes works exactly the same way. You upload it, they store it, somebody else downloads it. If you want direct peer-to-peer transfer, that's more complicated from an infrastructure perspective and there are many tools for that already out there. You can send it over any instant-messaging client, use something like Bittorrent Sync, make a VPN and share a folder or many other ways.

Comment: you mean to say!! pipebytes upload it on there website first and then download the same on other side and after completion of it. they delete from there server.

Comment: I meant to say exactly what I meant to say, whether they remove it after it's been downloaded or not is not the main point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "file is sent to the recipient" is slightly misleading, as far as I can see there is no real peer-to-peer process involved here. The file is stored on their server, and delivered to the recipient if they manage to enter the correct code.

Steps:

```
File upload
Storing the file somewhere in the filesystem
Storing the code specified by the user somewhere, e.g. a database
Sending an E-Mail to the recipient
Serving the file to the recipient
```